# "publishing delayed - Broad host permissions" warning even if content script is not executed on all pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension, publish, content-script

Whenever I try to publish a new update to my Chrome extension, I get a warning "publishing delayed - Broad host permissions". And I have to wait for 4-5 days to get it actually published.

If a user reports a bug in extension, providing the fix will have a turnaround time of a week although fix is minor which is damn frustrating! :( You cannot test patience of my users.

**Talking specifically about "Broad host permissions":**

Reading through many articles and forums, I got to know that if the content script is injected on any website without specifying host, it becomes a security concern for users. 
I agree to this and thanks to Chromium team for securing us from malicious extensions.

But my extension injects content script only on a specific set of pages where URL contains a specific query parameter.

I cannot disclose details of my product on public forum but let me cover this with an example. Let this query parameter be "my_company_parameter".

```
{
  "matches": [ "http://*/*my_company_parameter=*", "https://*/*my_company_parameter=*" ],
  "js": [ "content_client.js" ],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}
```

As you can see the extensions loads some tools on any page that is opened using query parameter "my_company_parameter" and does not bother other URLs.

Question is how does it become a security concern for users? Why the hell they will install the extension or use this query parameter if they don't wish to use my product.

The URL pattern is not as open as `https://*/*` but still I have to suffer from delayed review process.

Does it mean that any generic utility extension which works on different pages regardless of host will suffer through this?

What if I don't specify these scripts in manifest but execute from Background script by intercepting document requests? Will it fasten the publish process?

Comment: 1) If your extension has `"tabs"` permission it can automatically append the query parameter to any tab URL so that the content script will automatically run. 2) To be able to run on all URL you'll still need a broad host permissions, unless you go the [optional permissions route](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you think removing "tabs" permission from manifest will no more complain about "Broad host permissions"?

Comment: Only if you emphasize in a message to the reviewers that this was the only possible way to elevate the scope, and maybe ask them to confirm with their API specialist e.g. Devlin Cronin or Karan Bhatia.

Comment: @wOxxOm Really thanks for the pointers. Do you know what's the best way to reach out to them? I've already posted the question in google group but didn't get any response.

Comment: I think you can reply to the email they're sending, but I may be wrong.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not getting any emails. Though I have written to Devlin and Karan, waiting for their response.